# Unable to delete file in XP_CMDSHELL

Tags: sql-server

```
Alter proc GenerateBackup
   @DatabaseName varchar(255)='ABL_UAT',
   @BackupPath varchar(255)='D:\DataBase\DBBackup',
   --@FileSize int,

   @CompressedBackupPath varchar(max) ='D:\DataBase\DBBackup'
as
begin
   declare @SQLText nvarchar(max)
   declare @BackupName varchar(max)
   declare @CompressionCommand varchar(5000)
   declare @delete varchar(255)
      set @BackupName=@DatabaseName+'_' + replace(convert(date,getdate()),'-','_') 
   if (@CompressedBackupPath is null OR @CompressedBackupPath='')
   begin
      set @CompressedBackupPath=@BackupPath
      print @CompressedBackupPath
      set @SQLText= 'Backup database [' + @DatabaseName + '] to disk ='''+@BackupPath + '\'+@BackupName + '.bak'' with compression,copy_only'
      set @CompressionCommand='"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -v'+'M ' 
          + @CompressedBackupPath + '\' + @BackupName +'.rar '+@BackupPath + '\'+@BackupName + '.bak'
      set @delete=  'XP_CMDSHELL ''DEL' + '"' +@BackupPath + '\'+@BackupName + '.bak'  + '"' + ''''
   end
   else
   begin
      set @SQLText= 'Backup database [' + @DatabaseName + '] to disk ='''+@BackupPath + '\'+@BackupName + '.bak'' with compression,copy_only'
      set @CompressionCommand='"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -v'+'M ' 
          + @CompressedBackupPath + '\' + @BackupName +'.rar '+@BackupPath + '\'+@BackupName + '.bak'
      set @delete=  'XP_CMDSHELL ''DEL' + '"' +@BackupPath + '\'+@BackupName + '.bak'  + '"' + ''''
   end
  exec sp_executesql @SQLText
  exec xp_cmdshell @CompressionCommand

   EXEC @delete

 --  print @delete

     --EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'DEL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\CARS_BACKUP.BAK"'
end
```

Comment: Unable? Please share the error message. You should avoid using this SP. The issue is likely to be your SQL Server service account.

Comment: You can't delete the original .bak file while WinRAR still has it open compressing it. Use WinRAR's `m` command (move files to archive) instead of `a` (add files to archive), allowing it to delete the .bak file when it finishes.

Comment: ''DEL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Take a look at the error message. You have an extra single quote in there. It astounds me the number of people who 1. Don't post error messages; 2. Expect their dynamic SQL to just work first time without inspecting it. Please edit your question and add the error message.